# How to see if an ArrayList contains an entire term and that term only?

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to create a conditional statement if my ArrayList of contains a specific integer, e.g. 4. I was initially thinking:

```
if (arrlist.contains(4)){
  ***insert statements***
}
```

But then I realised that it would be set to true for like 40, 451, 14, etc. Is there a way to ask the arraylist to check if it matches, instead of if it contains.

I'm sure this has been asked before but I couldn't find anything that wasn't referring to contains. Thanks.

Comment: No it won't. It is a list thus would only look for 4. you are describing a String where you would have issues with 4, 451 and so on.

Comment: Why would it return true ? Are you modifying the arrayList in some way ?

Comment: @kar ok thanks, so for ints i don't have to worry about it, thanks!

Comment: @user13292868 It would be the same for a list of String too. See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You are describing Strings. Your if condition would work fine for lists.

Test it out yourself with the following:

```
//will find 4 since 4 is in list.
List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(4, 451);
System.out.println(ints.contains(4)); // true

// won't find it cos 451 is not 4.  
List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(5, 451);
System.out.println(ints.contains(4)); //false
```

Same for a String array.

```
    List<String> s = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "da");
    System.out.println(s.contains("a")); // true

    List<String> s = Arrays.asList("z", "b", "c", "da");
    System.out.println(s.contains("a")); //false
```

You would need to be more careful with Strings where if you are looking for an exact match of 4 and not wanting to find it if you have 451.

```
String s = "451";
System.out.println(s.contains("4"));
```

The above would be true which may not be something you wanted.